# ArrayStoreException when updating a bundle

Tags: osgi, classloader, apache-felix

Using Apache Felix I'm getting an ArrayStoreException when updating a bundle. It occurs in a different bundle to the one updated. The affected bundle has a service listener which reacts to a new service being registered by the updated bundle. The listener performs some code which ends in the ArrayStoreException. Here's the stack trace:

```
ERROR: Bundle com.elsten.bliss.platform [47] EventDispatcher: Error during dispatch. (java.lang.ArrayStoreException: com.elsten.bliss.music.policy.tag.tagtype.TagTypePolicy)
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: com.elsten.bliss.music.policy.tag.tagtype.TagTypePolicy
        at com.elsten.bliss.main.Main.getPolicies(Main.java:473)
        at com.elsten.bliss.main.Main.<init>(Main.java:150)
        at com.elsten.bliss.main.Main.startup(Main.java:143)
        at com.elsten.bliss.main.Activator$VersionServiceTracker.addingService(Activator.java:58)
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:980)
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:906)
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:262)
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:234)
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:941)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeServiceListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:932)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:793)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireServiceEvent(EventDispatcher.java:543)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireServiceEvent(Felix.java:4260)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.registerService(Felix.java:3275)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:346)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:352)
        at com.elsten.osgi.Activator.start(Activator.java:28)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:641)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:1977)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1895)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:944)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:931)
        at org.apache.felix.bundlerepository.impl.ResolverImpl.deploy(ResolverImpl.java:647)
        at com.elsten.bliss.updater.OnlineUpdater$2.run(OnlineUpdater.java:100)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

The code in getPolicies (**which is a static method**) accessess a **static final** variable:

```
private static final MusicPolicy tagTypePolicy = new TagTypePolicy();
private static MusicPolicy[] policies;
private static MusicPolicy[] getPolicies(Version version) {

    if(policies==null) {
        final HttpClientConfiguration httpClientConfig = HttpClientConfigurations.userAgentAndAcceptGzip(version);
        policies = new MusicPolicy[] {
            tagTypePolicy
        };
    }
    return policies;
}
```

My guess is that this is related to classloading; the MusicPolicy or TagTypePolicy classes do not match after the update. I'm a little confused why this would be the case; given these are **private** static variables I though my code could do what it liked. It's only when the statics are exported to other bundles, I thought, that trouble could happen.

Comment: I think it is necessary to see what the imports/exports are for the bundles. It is also a bit odd that the policies was not initialized, you would assume that after an update it would still be initialized? Did you just update bundle B and not stop bundle A (or gets stopped)?

Comment: Only one bundle is involved here... one that is being updated. OBR is used to provision the bundles, so I think the bundle should be stopped before the update.